# Add two duplicate columns in a data frame and remove the duplicates

Tags: r

I have a presence/absence data frame structured as following:

```
df <- structure(list(TargetFID = c(89L, 90L, 91L, 136L, 137L, 150L), 
               Cephaloscyllium.cooki = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
               Cephaloscyllium.fasciatum = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
               Cephaloscyllium.fasciatum.1 = c(0, 0, 1L, 0, 0, 0), 
               Cephaloscyllium.hiscosellum = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
 


TargetFID Cephaloscyllium.cooki Cephaloscyllium.fasciatum Cephaloscyllium.fasciatum.1 Cephaloscyllium.hiscosellum
1        89                     0                         1                           0                           0
2        90                     0                         0                           0                           0
3        91                     0                         0                           1                           0
4       136                     0                         0                           0                           0
5       137                     0                         0                           0                           0
6       150                     0                         0                           0                           0
```

Each row is a unique spatial grid cell with a corresponding unique ID.

Due to taxonomic changes some species that were previously recognised as different species have now been merged together forming one species, as seen with Cephaloscyllium.fasciatum above.

Hence, I have 14 duplicate columns (species) out of 1054 columns which I want to join together and remove the duplicated columns. There may be up to 3 of the same duplicated column.

Desired output:

```
TargetFID Cephaloscyllium.cooki Cephaloscyllium.fasciatum Cephaloscyllium.hiscosellum
1        89                     0                         1                           0
2        90                     0                         0                           0
3        91                     0                         1                           0
4       136                     0                         0                           0
5       137                     0                         0                           0
6       150                     0                         0                           0
```

Any advice would be much appreciated! (This is my first stack post so if the format is wrong/confusing please say.)

Comment: Welcome! It will make it easier for people to help you if you use dput rather than str to share you data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R way.

1. Get the unique data.frame names in a vector, `uniq`;
2. The first column is `ID` so`sapply` to all but the first name (`uniq[-1]`);
3. the anonymous function `\(u)` (R 4.1.0, for earlier versions use `function(u)`);
4. the function finds the columns matching each name `u`
5. and sums the values, row per row.

Note that the function could easily be a one-liner, I'm leaving it like this to be more readable.
Then it's a matter of binding the columns together with the `ID` column. Since `cbind` is generic and the call is on the data.frame `df1["ID"]`, the method called is the `cbind.data.frame` method and the result is a df.

```
uniq <- unique(names(df1))
temp <- sapply(uniq[-1], \(u){
  j <- which(names(df1) %in% u)
  rowSums(df1[j])
})
df2 <- cbind(df1["ID"], temp)

df2
#    ID SPP2 SPP3 SPP4
#1   89    0    0    0
#2   90    1    0    0
#3   91    0    0    0
#4  136    0    0    1
#5  137    0    0    0
#6  150    0    0    0
#7  154    0    0    0
#8  155    1    0    1
#9  158    0    0    0
#10 159    0    0    0
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <-
structure(list(ID = c(89, 90, 91, 136, 137, 150, 154, 155, 158, 
159), SPP2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), SPP2 = c(0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SPP3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), SPP4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SPP4 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R way using `split.default` -

```
tmp <- df[-1]
cbind(df[1], sapply(split.default(tmp, sub('\\.\\d+$', '', names(tmp))), 
             rowSums, na.rm = TRUE))

#  TargetFID Cephaloscyllium.cooki Cephaloscyllium.fasciatum Cephaloscyllium.hiscosellum
#1        89                     0                         1                           0
#2        90                     0                         0                           0
#3        91                     0                         1                           0
#4       136                     0                         0                           0
#5       137                     0                         0                           0
#6       150                     0                         0                           0
```

This answer relies on the fact that the duplicate columns would have `'.number'` in them. `sub` removes that part and `split.default` splits the data based on common column name. Using `rowSums` we sum the values rowwise for each group and return only one column.

Answer (score 0):

We could do

```
 un1 <- sub("\\.\\d+", '', names(df)[-1])
 cbind(df[1],  sapply(un1, function(x) rowSums(df[grep(x, names(df))])))
```